# Why is PST (America/Los_Angeles) time conversion to UTC, 1 hour behind?

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I have sensor data with a timestamp known to be in PST (Pacific Standard Time). Let's say that the timestamp is: `2020-10-21 10:00:00`. I want to convert that timestamp to UTC. UTC-to-PST conversion is UTC-8. So the *expected* timestamp in UTC is 8 hours forward: `2020-10-21 18:00:00`.

I tried to do the conversion:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> ts = datetime(2020,10,21,10,0,0)
>>> ts_local = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles').localize(ts, is_dst=False)
>>> ts_local.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z')
'2020-10-21 10:00:00 PDT-0700'
>>> ts_local.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z')
'2020-10-21 17:00:00 UTC+0000'
```

But you can see that the conversion is 1 hour behind what is expected. This  seems to make sense since `ts_local` appears to be in `PDT`. However, because I'd set `is_dst=False`, I expected `ts_local` to be in `PST`.

- I've tried `is_dst=True` and `is_dst=None` (even though those flag values don't make sense since the timestamp is in Standard Time) but the resulting `ts_local` remains in `PDT`.
- I've tried this conversion in Python 3.7.4 and Python 2.7.17 and gotten the same result.
- I've also tried this conversion using the `'US/Pacific'` pytz timezone but same issue.

I've read some other SO answers for how to do the conversion and what I've done is what has been suggested.

Comment: `ts_local` *isn't* in PST; it's in PDT. `is_dst` is being ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information given in the question, to me, setting a *time zone* (that has DST changes!) is the wrong approach if you simply have a fixed offset from UTC by x hours in your data. This assumes that your sensor's clock doesn't have DST changes coded into its memory.

My suggestion would therefore be to use a fixed offset tzinfo:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

dt = datetime.fromisoformat("2020-10-21 10:00:00")

# we know dt is UTC-8, so you can set the fixed offset:
dt_tzset = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=-8)))

# now you can convert to UTC easily:
dt_utc = dt_tzset.astimezone(timezone.utc)
print(dt_utc)
# 2020-10-21 18:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: This might perhaps accomplish the goal of setting a UTC-8 fixed offset, but it's important to call out that that would *not* be at all related to Pacific Time for the date and time given.  The only land-based time zone on Earth that is fixed to UTC-8 is `Pacific/Pitcairn`  (Pitcairn Islands, total population 43 persons as of Jan 2020).

Comment: @MattJohnsonPint: for one, this *does* accomplish the task of converting fixed offset to UTC, second I deliberately did not use the words time zone or Pacific time. Based on my experience with such sensor data, this would be my approach, that's all.

Comment: That makes sense. The timestamp is conveniently in PST, which doesn't account for daylight saving offset, so I'd just need to add 8 hours to my PST timestamp to get a UTC timestamp. This is true year-around. If, on the other hand, my sensor's timestamps were in PDT, then nothing need be done because `2020-10-21 17:00:00 UTC` is the correct UTC timestamp for `2020-10-21 10:00:00 PDT`. Come Nov 1 2020, when daylight savings ends, `2020-11-03 10:00:00 PDT` would have a UTC-8 offset: `2020-11-03 18:00:00 UTC`.

Comment: The underlying problem seems to be that associating time-zone info with a `datetime` object (through the call `pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles').localize(ts, is_dst=False)`) implicitly creates a PDT (Pacific Daylight-savings Time) datetime. This wasn't appropriate since my timestamp was in PST. So a fair follow-up question would be "how to create a PST timestamp"?

Comment: @MinhTran, the question is: your data's source, is it a clock that can be set to show time in a certain time zone (including programmed DST changes!) or does your clock only show the time it is set to and increment strictly monotonically? In the first case, it would make sense to specify a time zone, in the second case it does not. A fixed offset is sufficient. You can still convert to UTC and from there to any time zone you wish for further processing/display.

Comment: @MrFuppes The latter; it's got a non-time zone, non-DST-aware clock. The dev who programmed it told me it was set to PST time. I think I understand your suggestion now: don't use `.timezone().localize()`, just add the offset.

Comment: @MinhTran: ok, then you're good to go with a fixed offset :)

Answer (score 2):

From [the pytz docs](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/#tzinfo-api):

> The `is_dst` parameter is ignored for most timestamps. It is only used during DST transition ambiguous periods to resolve that ambiguity.

There is no ambiguity about `2020-10-21 18:00:00` in `America/Los_Angeles`.  It is unambiguously UTC-7 (PDT).

An example of an ambiguous timestamp in `America/Los_Angeles` is `2020-11-01 01:00:00` because there are two of them due to the DST fall-back transition.  The first is 01:00 PDT, the second is 01:00 PST.

Comment: Also, please be aware that pytz is no longer necessary.  Starting with Python 3.9, time zone support is built in.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html